# restricting numbers of digit length in regex

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

Here is my regex to validate a phone number.

```
((^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$)|(\(?[2-9][0-8][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}))|(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}
```

[Here is the link for regex check http://regex101.com/r/xO4aU4](http://regex101.com/r/xO4aU4)

it validates UK US numbers. lower bound of Range of the number is 7 and higher bound is not restricted.

can I restrict it so that if range of the number is if less then 7 or greater then 14 then it should not filter the number at all.

Comment: first - wow that is over-engineered! second - much better to just use php to check the length before passing it to your regex, third - when i put 01772 99 88 77 it doesn't match - and that is how I would type my phone number!

Comment: is it UK number? @GrahamRitchie

Comment: yes that is uk phone number - it is just that i split my number into pairs.

Comment: Your regex only start matching at 8 digits not 7.

Comment: Yuo may want to check this: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.aa-asterisk.org.uk/index.php/Regular_Expressions_for_Validating_and_Formatting_GB_Telephone_Numbers&client=firefox-a&hs=kn4&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&strip=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\+44)?\s?\(?0?\d{1,5}\)?\s\d{1,7}\s{0,1}\d{0,6}(?:\s-\s|\s)\s{0,2}\d{0,6}|(\+44)?\s?\(?\d{1,5}\)?\s\d{1,7}\s{0,1}\d{0,4}\s{0,1}\d{0,4}|(\+44)?\s?\(\d{1,5}\)\s?\d{3,7}\s?\d{0,4}\s?\d{0,4}|\d{4,5}\s*\d{3,5}\s\d{3,4}
```

That is a regex I use for Uk phone numbers (landlines) <- it is used in screen scraping sites so it is probably a little more robust and matches edge cases (such as people who put +44(0)1772 99 33 66) - it is used couple with string length checks and doesn't account for extension numbers - but you should put extension numbers as seperate field anyway.

I have no idea about US numbers so sorry can't help there!

Comment: thanks, I think this does not include mobile numbers. What should I do for including mobile nos too? I am not GB resident, dont have much idea about it

Comment: this is one of london number which is not filtered by regex : 020 7738 3021

Comment: bear in mind that I also use trim, string length, check only numeric +, - and () are in the string as well - not everything should be done by the regex.